# Why CefSharp not working fine?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

i'm newbie on cef, i run the sample code and i look not show fine, also a resize is not work, i install cef from nuget package manager, a last version of course. 
[image: Example Form]

My Main Form

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.youtube.com")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };

        toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
```

Comment: Compare your project to the `MinimalExample`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample You can fork that to reproduce your problem if indeed there is one.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a non-default display DPI setting in your environment? This may cause improper scaling of the embedded control.

We have faced and resolved a very similar issue when developing our own Chromium-based C# component for WinForms.